# How to add multiple lore statements

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

so, I have been trying to figure out how to add multiple lines of lore in place of enchantments, how do I phrase this... it displays **Power enchantment.level.32767** where I only want it to be **Power 32767**, but then I would like to place multiple lore lines that say like **Flame 32767** any thing I can do to create this?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply running this command:

```
/give {player} {item} {amount} {display{Name:'[{"text":"<name>","italic":"false","color":"<color>"}]',Lore:['[{"text":"<lore>","italic":"false","color":"<color>"}]']},Enchantments:[{id:<enchantment>,lvl:<level>}],HideFlags:1} 1
```

Example:

```
/give Player diamond_sword 1{display{Name:'[{"text":"A Sword","color":"blue","italic":"false"}]',Lore:['[{"text":"Sharpness LXX","color":"grey","italic":"false"}]']}, Enchantments:[{id: sharpness,lvl:70}],HideFlags:1} 1
```

What the command does is hides the enchantments using NBT data, so the enchantments won't appear in the lore but the enchantment will still work, you can also add more lines of lore and more enchantments using that template, if you need anymore help, or have any more questions feel free to ask me!